# How can I make a form with JSON data

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I want to make an attendance form where a list of users will show from JSON, i want each user to have his/her own value for the selected radio button.
JSON example:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "user 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "user 2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "user 3"
  },
]
```

This is the html example of what I want to do:

[image: this is the html example of what I want to do]

Comment: Did you check some flutter tutorials ? there are many ways to do this, im starting up with flutter too (few days in) and im trying to learn the BLoC pattern, the way i would do this is to follow BLoC's guidelines, create the bloc (including events + states), create a repository, provider (to fetch the data from the remote API) , and the model class to structure your data, and then you can show your data in your UI

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: Here is a good example of using BLoC to do consume an API: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterweathertutorial, here is another one from Flutter docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot to unpack in this question. A good place to start is the *data* side of the implmentation. Ideally, you'l want a dedicated class to work with the user data and JSON conversions.

`user.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class User {
  int _id;
  String name;
  User(
    this._id,
    this.name,
  );

  // A map is dart object
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      '_id': _id,
      'name': name,
    };
  }

  // With this 'factory' you can generate an object from a Map object directly.
  factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;

    return User(
      map['_id'],
      map['name'],
    );
  }

  // Dart interprets Json as string, so it needs, to be encoded and decoded to and from  dart objects.
  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  // With this 'factory' you can generate an object from a json string directly.
  factory User.fromJson(String source) => User.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

We won't use the methods in the case below, but the JSON encoding options should help you out in the future for implementations.

Now we can start on the *UI* part. This is a simple application that isn't quite storing data but showing how you can present it - `feel free to take/use this code`.

`main.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'user.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Some example users
    List<User> users = [
      User(1, 'Tom'),
      User(2, 'Sam'),
      User(3, 'Alex'),
    ];
    return MaterialApp(home: Home(users: users));
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<User> users;
  const Home({Key key, this.users}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('User Data')),
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: widget.users.length,
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Divider();
        },
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          var name = widget.users[index].name;
          var id = widget.users[index].id;
          return CustomListTile(name: name, id: id);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum Attendance { present, absent }

class CustomListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final int id;

  CustomListTile({
    Key key,
    this.name,
    this.id,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomListTileState createState() => _CustomListTileState();
}

class _CustomListTileState extends State<CustomListTile> {
  Attendance attendance = Attendance.absent;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Text('${widget.name} (${widget.id})'),
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Text('Present'),
          Radio(
            value: Attendance.present,
            groupValue: attendance,
            onChanged: (Attendance value) {
              setState(() => attendance = value);
            },
          ),
          Text('Absent'),
          Radio(
            value: Attendance.absent,
            groupValue: attendance,
            onChanged: (Attendance value) {
              setState(() => attendance = value);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is one way to help you get started. Then you'll likely need to store/track these records in a record store (ie database), but you can do that in the `onChange` `Radio` methods or in a state management solution.